# iTunes song name

Tags: itunes, macos, itunes-radio

I am listening to my local radio (www.otvoreni.hr) using iTunes (i have downloaded stream.pls file and opened it with iTunes) and it is playing properly.
Now, no matter how much i tried, i cant find an option to show current song name/artist... and it is driving me crazy -.-

Anybody have any advices? Attached is iTunes screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stream you are listening to does not provide artist/title information. I confirmed this by playing the stream in VLC. VLC (and iTunes) both show artist/title information when playing a stream from [CRIK FM](http://www.lynxradionetwork.com/listen.htm#.), for example.

Comment: Oh, my bad than, since they have current song infos on their site, i tough they would have it in their streaming file as well.Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. If you feel this sufficiently answered your question, please feel free to click the checkmark to the left to accept this answer.